# How do you find the local timezone offset in rust

Tags: rust

Rust's `chrono::Local` contains the local timezone information but does not seem to have any methods to get the value as a string or a number of seconds offset.

Any idea's how to get the correct local offset so that

```
DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339([iso8601 date] + [timezone]).unwrap().with_timezone(&Local)
```

will return a `DateTime` that is in the default current timezone of the computer the code is running on.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```rust
Local.timestamp(0, 0).offset().fix().local_minus_utc()
```

which returns the local offset to UTC in seconds (eg. it returns 3600 on my CET system).

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd4ee8212bb766edbd0d8d2159d0d913), which seems to use UTC and hence returns 0)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `chrono` crate and use the following snippet to get the timezone offset.

```rust
use chrono::Local;
let offset_in_sec = Local::now()
    .offset()
    .local_minus_utc();
eprintln!("offset: {:?}", offset_in_sec);
```

If you're using the `time` crate, then you can use the following snippet to get the
timezone offset from `offset_in_sec` above.

```rust
use time::UtcOffset;
let utc_offset_result = UtcOffset::from_whole_seconds(offset_in_sec);
eprintln!("utc_offset_result: {:?}", offset_in_sec);
```

1. You can see a real example in `r3bl_rs_utils` crate here - https://github.com/r3bl-org/r3bl-rs-utils/blob/main/src/utils/file_logging.rs
2. For more information, you can also checkout: https://developerlife.com/category/Rust/

Answer (score -3):

For the moment I have a hacky solution that works on Linux only

```
/// returns local timezone "+01:00"
fn tz() -> String {
    let output = Command::new("date").arg("+%:z").output()
                 .expect("failed to fetch timezone");
    String::from(String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).trim())
}
```